# How to find unique number from a user inputted sequence, if there is one

Tags: java, unique

User will input a sequence of numbers, integers separated with commas, like this 2,3,1,245,2,75. How can I find if there is a number that is not duplicated and print it back ? I got so far this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    String[] line2;

    line = reader.nextLine();
    line2= line.split(",");
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0; i<line2.length; i++){
        System.out.println(line2[n]);
        n++;
    }
}
```

What this does is: stores the input in string "line" and then removes the commas and stores only the numbers in "line2". And then prints the content of line2 but thats not necessary I did it just to see if it works, what i need to print is just the unique number.

Answer (score 4):

You could stream the array you get from splitting the strings, create a frequency map of it, and keep just the numbers that appear once:

```
List<String> unique =
        Arrays.stream(input.split(","))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                             Collectors.counting()))
              .entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @ItamarGreen frequency is an O(n) operation, and you perform it per element of the collection, resulting in O(n^2). Here, you have one O(n) on the array to create the frequency map and another O(m) where (m <= n) pass to find only the unique items, for a total of O(n).

Comment: Is it? I thought otherwise. If it is then I apologize. But that's what's it's about; learning from mistakes

Comment: @ItamarGreen Couldn't agree more. To your question - yes, it is. Without making assumptions on a Collection's implementation, there's nothing much to do but to iterate over the elements of the collection one by one, making it an O(n) operation. Examining [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk/blob/jdk8u/jdk8u/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L5266) confirms this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array and check whether there are copies for each element.

```
for(String x:line2){
    if(unique(x, line2))
        System.out.println(x+" is a unique number");
}
```

---

Here's the `unique()` function that checks for copies.

```
private static boolean unique(String x, String[] line2){
    for(String i:line2){
        if(i.equals(x))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the numbers in a `List<>` and then use `Collections.frequency()`, which is more efficient than iterating over the collection yourself:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
String[] line2;
line = reader.nextLine();
line2= line.split(",");
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<line2.length; i++){
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(line2[i]));
}
boolean flag = true;
for(int a : list){
    if(Collections.frequency(list, a)!=1){
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: this might throw NumberFormatException if the user put something which isn't a number*

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8's Streams: I first filter the Array of Strings to remove all duplicates, than check if the string is unique and finally print all unique Strings out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class UniqueNumberScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        String[] line2;

        line = reader.nextLine();

        line2 = line.split(",");
        Stream.of(line2).distinct().filter(item -> Stream.of(line2).filter(item::equals).count() == 1).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```